# TVS diodes routing on USB data lines

Tags: pcb-design, usb, layout, signal-integrity

I have decided to use bidirectional TVS diodes for ESD protection on the USB data lines. Nevertheless, the pads of the diodes create a discontinuity of the tracks.

So, what is the best way to route them, integrity wise, in order to minimize the issue?

Below are the 4 possible ways I have come up with:

**Option 1**

[image]

**Option 2**

[image]

**Option 3**

[image: Option 3]

**Option 4**

[image]

I believe option 4 would be the worst possible and I am in favor of option 2.

Lastly, I am using FT232H as the USB controller. According to p.42 of the [datasheet](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/DS_FT232H.pdf), the device has been subjected to ESD testing and provides tolerance for HM, MM and CDM. Yet the manufacturer recommends the use of TVS diodes in the provided schematics on pages 43, 44, 45. Since it is ESD tolerant, are the TVS diode a little bit of overkill in that case? Thank you.

Comment: I think #3, in theory, but definitely defer to others w/ more experience here. Maybe closer to the connector too. And consider a combined TVS device designed for USB lines, although harder to actually buy of late. Some of the manufacturers there also have app notes / guidance on layout...

Comment: Option 1 is shown in Figure 11 of [Application Note ANP002c by Würth Elektronik](https://www.we-online.com/components/media/o109030v410%20AppNotes_ANP002_TheProtectionOfUSB20Applications_EN.pdf).

Comment: @root Interesting, I honestly did not expect to see this as a recommended layout. The Application Note was an interesting read, thanks for you comment.

Comment: As a note to this old question, for anyone interested, I finally decided to scrap the TVS diode in that design, because a) I could not conclude to a layout that seemed satisfactory signal integrity-wise b) as mentioned in the OP, "... the device has been subjected to ESD testing and provides tolerance for HM, MM and CDM." So I did not want to risk any signal integrity issues since the IC is compliant wiith ESD testing. Design still works well as of today, so I guess omitting them was not, at least, fatal. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the options given, option 2 is probably the best bet. Changing the line spacing between a differential pair is generally frowned upon, as it will change the line impedance locally, causing reflections and ultimately harming signal integrity by some amount.

A common practice is to change the width to accommodate this, such that the line impedance remains the same. However, since there is a big stub there in the form of the SMD footprint, any change made is largely dwarfed by both the parasitics of the SMD package and the pads themselves. As this discontinuity is appreciably smaller than the wavelength for USB 2.0 HS, there is likely little difference between 2 and 3.

Option 4 is odious mainly because it constitutes nothing but a giant stub. Yes, the differential pair spacing does remain the same, but that effect is minuscule in comparison to the stub and parasitics of the TVS route. I have seen USB 2.0 run on worse, but that's a great counterexample if nothing else.

Helpful guidance from Texas Instruments about this matter is available [here on pages 12 and 13, section 3.10](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/spraar7j/spraar7j.pdf).

Consider also a dedicated TVS solution designed for high-speed systems like the [TPD2E009 from TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpd2e009.pdf) or the [SP1004U from Littelfuse](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diode_arrays/littelfuse_tvs_diode_array_ultra_low_capacitance_diode_arrays_datasheet.pdf.pdf). These have lower parasitic capacitance than the usual TVS diode and route quite nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the original post I was going with TVS diodes recommended by FTDI, in the design example. The recommended ICs are an interesting choice, also it's great that the TI's datasheet provides some example layout, probably I will use one of them in one of the next designs.